# Filtering a pandas dataframe column with is a numpy.ndarry

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need a method to filter a pandas column that is a numpy.ndarry. I need to filter on where the cell is 'True'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame('id_num':['id_1','id_2,'id_3','id_4',id_5], 'Required':[['False'],['False,True'],['False'],['True, 'False'],['False']
```

df

```
Wanted:

id_num    Required
id_2      [False, True]
id_4      [True, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df[df.Required.explode().eq('True').max(level=0)]
```

output:

```
  id_num       Required
1   id_2  [False, True]
3   id_4  [True, False]
```

Comment: The Required column in my dataframe is a numpy.ndarry.  So both solutions are not working, since it is not list,

Comment: @JeffMagouirk please do `df.to_dict()` and copy the output to your question. Your sample data is ill-formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
df[pd.DataFrame(df.Required.tolist()).eq('True').any(1)]
  id_num       Required
1   id_2  [False, True]
3   id_4  [True, False]
```